# Assembly ANSI Escape Code: How do I add blinking?

Tags: assembly, ansi-escape

For a piece of assembly code I'm writing I want to print a blinking text in a specific colour. I have already managed to find out how to print my text in colour. However, I'm struggling with the blinking. Here's what I have:

```
string: .asciz "\033[38;5;94mTEXT\033[0m"
...
mov $string, %rdi
mov $0, %rax
call printf
```

How do I add blinking to this?

Answer (score 2):

The ANSI Escape sequence `\033[38;5;94m` selects a foreground color. To enable blinking use `\033[5m`

If you want blinking to last, then don't immediately reset all attributes with `\033[0m`! Give it some time to actually see the text blinking.

```
string: .asciz "\033[5m\033[38;5;94mTEXT"
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK blinking has to be explicitly enabled in videocard hardware.
Blinking concerns characters with background-color attribute between 8..15, which can be set by ANSII code.
I used a DOS utility [OPIN.com /Attr](http://www.vitsoft.info/#OPIN) to switch blinking on/off in emulation of real mode. It employs those TASM macros:

```
MACRO  DisableBlink ; Makes the background color bright instead of blinking.
       PUSH    DS
       SUB     BX,BX
       MOV     DS,BX
       MOV     DX,[0463h] ; CRTC port
       ADD     DL,4       ; mode select port
       MOV     AL,[0465h] ; old CRT mode
       AND     AL, NOT 20h; disable blink
       OR      AL,09h     ; visible text mode
       OUT     DX,AL      ; CGA,HGA
       MOV     [0465h],AL ; new CRT mode
       MOV     AX,1003h
       INT     10h        ; disable blink EGA
       POP     DS
ENDM

MACRO  EnableBlink ; Makes the background color blink.
       PUSH    DS
       SUB     BX,BX
       MOV     DS,BX
       MOV     DX,[0463h] ; CRT mode port
       ADD     DL,4       ; mode select port
       MOV     AL,[0465h] ; old CRT mode
       OR      AL,29h     ; enable blink
       OUT     DX,AL      ; CGA,HGA
       MOV     [0465h],AL ; new CRT mode
       MOV     AX,1003h
       INC     BL
       INT     10h        ; enable blink EGA
       POP     DS
ENDM
```

However, I'm not sure if this is possible in protected-mode programs.